# Program is generating a "error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed." error message in Skill.h file with valid user defined Object

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

In this program, the end goal I am trying to achieve is to simulate a game known as "Fire Emblem" in the form of simple text simulator. The main functionality here is through an abstract class known as Skill, which will then be inherited from by more specific sub classes that define a particular skill with a unique effect. Unfortunately, when the program is run, the above error is generated in the activate function of the Skill.h file, despite Unit being a object type that is already defined. I suspect this may have something to do with the #include order of the head files, but I see no other way to change the order with breaking functionality. Is there a way to avoid the possible re including of a .h file while keeping the logic I currently have in my program? Also, i apologize for the huge amount of code, I wasn't sure which bits to omit.

Skill.h

The purpose of this class is to serve as an abstract class from which more specific skill sub classes will inherit from and implement the activate() function.

```
#ifndef SKILL_H
#define SKILL_H
#include "Unit.h"

#include <string>
#include <random>

class Skill{
    public:
        Skill(const std::string &skillName);
        void setSkillLikelyHood(int chance);
        int getLikelyHood() const;
        std::string getSkillName() const;

        //this function generates the error messages specified in the title
        virtual void activate(const Unit &player, Unit &enemy ) = 0;
    protected:
        int random(int min, int max);
        int likelyHood;
        std::string skillName;
};

#endif // !1
```

Skill.cpp

```
#include "Skill.h"

Skill::Skill(const std::string &skillName) : skillName(skillName) {
}

void Skill::setSkillLikelyHood(int chance){
    likelyHood = chance;
}

int Skill::getLikelyHood() const{
    return likelyHood;
}

std::string Skill::getSkillName() const{
    return skillName;
}

int Skill::random(int min, int max){
    std::random_device seed;
    std::default_random_engine rnGen(seed());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(min, max);

    return dist(rnGen);
}
```

Astra.h

```
#ifndef ASTRA_H
#define ASTRA_H
#include "Skill.h"

class Astra : public Skill{
    public:
        Astra();
        void activate(const Unit &player, Unit &enemy) override;
};

#endif
```

Astra.cpp

```
#include "Astra.h"

Astra::Astra() : Skill("Astra"){

}

void Astra::activate(const Unit &player, Unit &enemy){
    std::cout << player.getName() << " activated " << skillName << " Oh no!\n";

    int damage = player.getDamageDealtToEnemy(enemy);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        //if the player lands a hit AND lands a crit, perform the crit against the enemy. 
        if (player.calculateHit(enemy) && player.calculateCriticalHit(enemy)) {
            std::cout << player.getName() << " landed a crit! " << enemy.getName() << " took " << damage << " damage!\n" ;
            enemy.getHp() -= damage;
        }

        //if the player managed to land a hit, but failed to crit, simply land a regular hit.
        else if (player.calculateHit(enemy)) {
            std::cout << player.getName << " dealt " << damage << " damage!\n";
            enemy.getHp() -= damage;
        }

        //otherwise, the player will miss their attack.
        else
            std::cout << "Attack missed!\n";

    }
}
```

Unit.h

```
#ifndef UNIT_H
#define UNIT_H

#include "Astra.h"
#include "Weapon.h"
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Unit{
    public:
        Unit(const std::string &name, const Weapon &weapon, const Skill &s);
        ~Unit();
        void levelUp();
        int &getHp();
        void attack(Unit &unit);
        std::string getName() const;
        int getDamageDealtToEnemy(const Unit &enemy) const;
        bool calculateHit(const Unit &enemy) const;
        bool calculateCriticalHit(const Unit &enemy) const;
        friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &os, const Unit &u);
    private:
        int random(int min, int max) const;
        void calculateStats();
        std::string name;
        std::array<int, 7> stats;
        std::array<int, 7> growthRates;
        std::unique_ptr<Skill> skill;
        Weapon weapon;
        int level, hp, avoid, criticalAvoid, hitRate, totalAttack, criticalRate, criticalChance, exp;
        static int turnNumber;
};

#endif
```

Unit.cpp

```
#include "Unit.h"

int Unit::turnNumber = 1;


Unit::Unit(const std::string &name, const Weapon &weapon, const Skill &s) : name(name), weapon(weapon), hp(100), level(1), exp(0),
skill(std::make_unique<Skill>()){

    for (int i = 0; i < stats.size(); i++) {
        stats[i] = random(20, 25);
        growthRates[i] = random(55, 80);
    }

    calculateStats();
    skill->setSkillLikelyHood(stats[2] / 2);

}

Unit::~Unit()
{
}

void Unit::levelUp(){
    hp += random(15, 20);

    for (int i = 0; i < stats.size(); i++){
        if (random(0, 100) < growthRates[i])
            stats[i] += random(2, 4);
    }
}

int &Unit::getHp(){
    return hp;
}

//This function
void Unit::attack(Unit &enemy){

    std::cout << "turn: " << turnNumber << "\n";
    std::cout << name << " attacked " << enemy.name << "!\n";

    //On the first turn, and only the first turn (as doing so after the first turn is unnecessary) calculate the player and the
    //enemy's stats after factoring in the weapon triangle bonus.
    if (turnNumber == 1) {
        weapon.determineWeaponTriangleBonus(enemy.weapon.getWeaponType());
        enemy.weapon.determineWeaponTriangleBonus(this -> weapon.getWeaponType());
        calculateStats();
        enemy.calculateStats();
    }

    switch (calculateHit(enemy)){
        int damage;

        //if you manage to land a hit....
        case true:
            //when you land a critical hit, you will deal three times normal damage!
            damage = (calculateCriticalHit(enemy)) ? (totalAttack - enemy.stats[5]) * 3  : (totalAttack - enemy.stats[5]);
            std::cout << name << "'s attack: " << totalAttack << "\n";
            enemy.hp -= damage;
            std::cout << enemy.name << " took " << damage << " damage! HP: " << enemy.hp << "\n\n";
            break; 
        case false:
            std::cout << name << " miss his attack! :(\n\n";
    }

    //base case. When either the player or enemy has died, end the recursive call
    if (enemy.hp <= 0) {
        std::cout << enemy.name << " is dead!\n";
        return;
    }

    turnNumber++;

    enemy.attack(*this);
}

std::string Unit::getName() const{
    return name;
}

int Unit::getDamageDealtToEnemy(const Unit &enemy) const{
    return totalAttack - enemy.stats[5];
}

int Unit::random(int min, int max) const{
    std::random_device seed;
    std::default_random_engine rnGen(seed());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(min, max);

    return dist(rnGen);
}

void Unit::calculateStats(){
    int &att = stats[0], &mag = stats[1], &skl = stats[2], &spd = stats[3], &lck = stats[4], &def = stats[5], 
        &res = stats[6];

    avoid = (spd * 2) + lck;
    criticalAvoid = lck / 2;
    hitRate = weapon.getAccuracy() + (skl * 2) + (lck / 2);
    criticalRate = skl + weapon.getCritical();
    totalAttack = att + weapon.getMight();
}

bool Unit::calculateHit(const Unit &enemy)const{
    std::cout << "hit rate: " << hitRate - enemy.avoid << "%\n";
    return ((random(0, 100) + random(0, 100)) / 2) < hitRate - enemy.avoid;
}

bool Unit::calculateCriticalHit(const Unit &enemy) const{
    //std::cout << "critical hit: " << criticalRate - unit.criticalAvoid << "%\n";
    return random(0, 100) < criticalRate - enemy.criticalAvoid;
}

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Unit & u){
    std::array<std::string, 7> statNames{"att", "mag", "skl", "spd", "lck", "def", "res"};

    std::cout << u.name << "'s hp: " << u.hp << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < statNames.size(); i++)
        os << statNames[i] << ": " << u.stats[i] << "\n";

    os << "Avoid: " << u.avoid << "\n";
    os << "hitRate: " << u.hitRate << "\n";
    os << "critical avoid: " << u.criticalAvoid << "\n";
    os << "critical rate: " << u.criticalRate << "\n";

    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are compiling class **Skill** at that time class **Unity** is not known to compiler. To make it available you have to do "**forward declaration**" of **Unity** class.

Add following line after the headers in Skill.h

```
class Unity;
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked out perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: @DarienMiller if it worked, then please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

OP has a circular dependency: Skill.h -> Unit.h -> Astra.h -> Skill.h.

While OPs include guardians terminate the recursion (which otherwise would raise a compiler error – something like "Too many nested includes"), it ends up with a type usage (in one of the headers) which is not possible as the previous type definition is missing (due to effective header guardian).

Circular dependencies should be prevented. Alternatively, forward declarations should be used.

Please note, to use a pointer or reference to a type, an incomplete type is sufficient (e.g. `class Unit;`).

So, declarations in headers might be based on forward declarations. Hence, at least, one of the circular dependent `#include`s can be removed.

Then, each of the three C++ files may `#include` all three headers without harm.

Comment: Excellent advice, everything worked out wonderfully. So about forward declarations, can they be used in place of #include "header.h", or should they only be used to prevent circular dependencies?

Comment: @DarienMiller Not that easy to answer. Incomplete types are worth for something but not for everything because (Surprise!) they are incomplete. In fact, some APIs like e.g. Qt use a lot of forward declarations (IMHO) to reduce header dependencies. Please, keep in mind that Qt is quite a big library, and includes with includes with includes doesn't make compiling faster. On the other hand, from maintenance aspect, I prefer one (and only one) type definition and use forward declarations in most cases exclusively to break circular dependencies.